# Rails callback after_save not setting attribute

Tags: activerecord, callback, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm dealing with a problem on a after_save callback. I'm sure there is a easy solution, but I can't figure it out.

I have 3 models: User, Product, Bid. The Product table contains a boolean field "available", which is set default to true. If a User places a bid, the available field should be set to false.
I thought this should work with a callback on the bid model.
I can access and set the available field in the console by typing:
    b = Bid.last
    b.product.available = false
    => false
However I can't change it via the controller, so I think it doesn't execute the callback. What am I doing wrong?
Thank you all for your help!

**product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

has_one :bid
belongs_to :user
end
```

**bid.rb**

```
class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :product_id, :user_id, :product
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :user
after_save :set_product_status

def set_product_status
self.product.available = false
end
end
```

**bids_controller.rb**

```
...
def create
@user = current_user
product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
@bid = @user.bids.build(product: product)

respond_to do |format|
if @bid.save
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since bid belongs_to product, you should save the product too.

```
def set_product_status
  self.product.available = false
  self.product.save
end
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked!
I found out, that it will also work with:
product.available = false
product.save

So it seems also not to need the "self"-reference.

Thank you a lot for your help!